# UIBarButtonItem appearance difference between iOS 5 and iOS 6

Tags: ios, uiimage, uibarbuttonitem, uiappearance

I'm using the appearance proxy to set the background image of the back button in the navigation bar.

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow-back-button"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0., 9., 0., 0.)]
                                                  forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

This works great for iOS 6, looks absolutely perfect. In iOS 5, however, the background image starts repeating, almost as if the button is taller or something.

iOS 5:

[image: iOS 5 version]

iOS 6:

[image: iOS 6 version]

The image used (with a coloured background to highlight the size).

[image: Back button image]

Can anyone help me make the back button look correct in iOS 5?

EDIT:

Here is the result if I don't use `resizableImageWithCapInsets:`.

[image: iOS 5 with no resizableImage]

Comment: Maybe it *is* taller.  Try manually setting its contentEdgeInsert property to see if that helps anything.

Comment: I don't think you can set the contentEdgeInset using the appearance protocol, so I'm not sure how I'd fit it into my code. Also I'm not sure why the image is repeating, surely it should just stretch if the button was taller?

Comment: Incorrect.  In iOS 5 the behavior of a resizable button is to tile.  Since your resizable portion is basically a good chunk of the right size, this fits exactly.  Why do you need a resizable button anyway? o,0  Do you expect these bar buttons to change height?

Comment: I don't expect the button to change height. See my edit if the image doesn't include `resizableImageWithCapInsets:`.

Comment: That's the result *without* ? I expected some absurd stretching.  You should try setting the *image* instead of the *background image* but then it will be in the middle.  Either that or make a PNG with lots of alpha in it.

Comment: Yeah that's the result if it's set with `... setBackButtonBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow-back-button"]...`. I've tried making the image the correct height for iOS 5 with transparency and I don't get any repeating image which is good. The button text is now vertically offset so I need to shift that back up somehow. I don't suppose you know how I can do that using the appearance protocol?

Comment: Oh hang on, it looks like `setTitlePositionAdjustment:forBarMetrics:` might work.

Comment: @borrrden want to add a proper answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tiling behavior you are experiencing is normal for iOS 5.x.  That is the only behavior it knows how to do to resize the image.  I don't know why it seems to resize in 5.x but not in 6.x, but the only way to fix this behavior in iOS 5.x is to make a PNG that is the same size as the background of your `UIBarButtonItem` (with alpha filler) and set that as a *non-resizable* background image.

Comment: You can still use resizable image. The only requirement is the image has to be 30pt high (as I wrote in my answer).

Answer (score 1):

If you use your image with Retina display then postfix your image with `@2x` : `"arrow-back-button@2x"`.

Try to create a category of `UIImage` and add this instance method:

```
 (UIImage*)resizableImageWithLeftCapWidth:(NSInteger)leftCapWidth topCapHeight:            (NSInteger)topCapHeight </b>{
UIImage *image = nil;    
float osVersion = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue];
if (osVersion < 6.0) {
    image = [self stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:leftCapWidth topCapHeight:topCapHeight];
} else {
    UIEdgeInsets edgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(topCapHeight, leftCapWidth, topCapHeight, leftCapWidth);
    image = [self resizableImageWithCapInsets:edgeInsets];
}
return image;
 }
```

I suspect there is an iOS 5 bug that has been fixed in iOS6

Comment: The image is named @2x. `[UIImage imageNamed:...]` will find the appropriate file for the current device. I don't think this is the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your background image to be 30px high (60px for retina version). Just add some transparent pixels at the top and the bottom so the arrow stays vertically centred.

iOS 5 forces the minimum height of 30pt and resizes your image if it's smaller.